# Numerical input and binary classification

Tags: python, tensorflow, lstm

I'm still learning deep learning with tensorflow and i had moved within LSTM a bit. I under stabd LSTM regression and did couple of models there. Now, I'm trying to to reach a regression like but classification where i want to classify labels value as greater then or less then. I have tried couple of existing codes but still didn't get the point.

My question is about below code:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(32,input_shape=(X_train.shape[1],X_train.shape[2]),return_sequences=True))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(1))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='binary_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(scipy.stats.zscore(X_train),y_train>=0.05,epochs=10,validation_split=0.2)
p = model.predict(scipy.stats.zscore(X_test))
```

sample of my features:

```
X_train[:2]

array([[[ 6.62364330e-04,  1.66358595e-02,  2.40295749e-02,
          1.84842884e-03,  1.84842884e-02, -1.06277840e+00,
          4.45218993e+01,  3.72895448e+07,  1.66694434e+04,
          4.86154015e+09,  7.67031510e-03],
        [ 6.62364330e-04,  1.47874307e-02,  1.66358595e-02,
          3.69685767e-03,  9.24214418e-03, -1.06706125e+00,
          4.10241215e+01,  1.89388276e+07,  1.49832496e+04,
          5.22004803e+09,  3.62809450e-03],
        [ 6.62364330e-04,  0.00000000e+00,  3.66300366e-03,
         -9.15750916e-03,  0.00000000e+00, -1.06193867e+00,
          4.10241215e+01,  1.09146703e+07,  1.14050891e+04,
          4.27086081e+09,  2.55561368e-03]],

       [[ 6.62364330e-04,  1.47874307e-02,  1.66358595e-02,
          3.69685767e-03,  9.24214418e-03, -1.06706125e+00,
          4.10241215e+01,  1.89388276e+07,  1.49832496e+04,
          5.22004803e+09,  3.62809450e-03],
        [ 6.62364330e-04,  0.00000000e+00,  3.66300366e-03,
         -9.15750916e-03,  0.00000000e+00, -1.06193867e+00,
          4.10241215e+01,  1.09146703e+07,  1.14050891e+04,
          4.27086081e+09,  2.55561368e-03],
        [ 6.62364330e-04, -1.97132616e-02, -1.79211470e-03,
         -2.68817204e-02, -1.07526882e-02, -1.04563298e+00,
          4.68368478e+01,  3.46075465e+07,  2.16567876e+04,
          4.76705234e+09,  7.25973706e-03]]])

y_train[:2]

array([-0.01075269, -0.00359712])

y_train[:2] >= 0.05

array([False, False])
```

Also, please note that labels are bias as true to false ratio as:

```
np.unique(y_train>=0.05, return_counts=True)
(array([False,  True]), array([164733,   4313]))
```

my questions are:

- How to get final results in the same label foems (True-False)
- What am doing wrong?

Comment: Is expected outputs dependent on each other (sequential)? If not using LSTMs really doesn't make so much sense also if you are doing a classification like that don't forget to use an activation function at the last layer as "softmax" or "sigmoid".

Comment: Yes, an output is a next day stock price. Data onnthe question is just an example.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, what's the point of writing a machine learning model to solve a problem, which can be solved perfectly with one line of code.

If it's just an experiment,

1. Get rid of the LTSM layers as suggested by Hakan, the inputs are random floating-point numbers with no relation between them. Use only dense layers.
2. Your last layer is 'linear', it would make more sense to use 'sigmoid' in the last layer.